SerializeField in singleton MonoBehaviour class
[machine translation English]
Problem
SingletonMono would create its gameobject after the game start, but my singleton class StageManager need to get Camera using [SerializeField].
How could I do that?
Or is there some better method to get Camera Object in a singleton MonoBehaviour?
I'd heard to avoid mounting singleton Monobehaviour Script to a gameobject by hand.
My SingletonMono Base Class
public abstract class SingletonMono<T>: MonoBehaviour where T: MonoBehaviour
{
    private static T _instance;
    protected static bool ApplicationIsQuitting;
    protected static bool IsGlobal;

    
    static SingletonMono()
    {
        ApplicationIsQuitting = false;
        IsGlobal = false;
    }

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (ApplicationIsQuitting)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning($"Application is quitting, you cant operate a singleton mono object: [{typeof(T)}]");
                return _instance;
            }
            
            _instance = FindObjectOfType<T>();
            if (FindObjectsOfType<T>().Length > 1)
            {
                Debug.LogError($"the singleton type [{typeof(T)}] has more than one instances");
                return _instance;
            }
            
            if (_instance is not null) return _instance;
            
            var obj = new GameObject(typeof(T).ToString());
            _instance = obj.AddComponent<T>();
            if(IsGlobal) DontDestroyOnLoad(obj);
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        ApplicationIsQuitting = true;
    }
}

My StageManager class
    public class StageManager: SingletonMono<StageManager>
    {
        [SerializeField] private float spaceOffset;
        [SerializeField] private Camera mainCam;

        public Vector3 GetWorldPositionByScreenPoint(Vector2 pos)
        {
            var z = -mainCam.transform.position.z;
            return mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, z));
        }
    }

How could I do that?

[SerializeField] is used to expose a private field in the Unity Editor, allowing it to be serialized and editable in the Inspector window even though it's not public. So you need to assign camera from inspector manually. I suggest you to this:
private Camera _mainCamera;

private void Awake()
{
    _mainCamera = Camera.main;
}

